# Literature on the uses and applications of Probability Distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, gamma-distribution

I'm a graduate mathematics student and I've taken several courses on statistics, probability theory, stochastic processes and machine learning.

In all the textbooks I consulted and all the classes I've taken so far there is a great amount of mathematical detail and explanations regarding the simple concepts of the subject at hand. Specifically in statistics and machine learning there is often a lot of text on the description of the problem.

However, as soon as the problem is given they go straight to the model distributions. E.g. in our course on insurance mathematics estimating the insurance premium was done using a **Poisson-Gamma** distribution approach. But while there was a great deal of discussion on the (lack of) importance of the horsepower of the insured car, there was no explanation for why we would use the Poisson or Gamma distributions in our model.

Everywhere I look it is just assumed I already know which distribution is best fitted to model a specific problem.

Do you know any literature that explains in detail what the variety of modelling distributions we have represent and when and why to use them?

Comment: In statistics you start from some observations to make an inference on the law of the random variables oberved. Sometimes (as in your case), it is assumed that the law is of a certain kind. Namely, that it is *parametrized* by a finite set of real numbers (parameters). But this is not always the case: check any book on *nonparametric* statistics. The class of distributions you start with can also express a previous *information* you have on the law you want to infer: you may want to review that information as you sample: check *Bayesian* statistics.

Comment: @Kore-N My question relates to the problem of how to choose the class of distributions. Which distributions best model which problems and why. 

I added that I had classes on machine learning before to make clear that I am familiar with general concepts like parametric and nonparametric statistics or Bayes.

Comment: Feller’s volume 1 probability textbook, though it is introductory, does an amazing job at motivating and presenting examples (somewhat rapidly) of the applications of e.g. the Poisson distribution, and how certain idealizations fail or only approximate a phenomena. One of the first chapters opens up with how many different things may be modeled by $r$ balls in $n$ bins to some degree (birthdays, accidents, firing (shooting), sampling, irradiation in biology, cosmic ray experiments, an elevator, dice, random digits, sex distributions, coupon collecting, aces in bridge, gene distributions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the book you are asking for:

Statistical Distributions 4th Edition, by Forbes, Evans, Hastings and Peacock, 2011, [freely available here](http://personalpages.to.infn.it/%7Ezaninett/pdf/statistical-distributions.pdf).

Then, I would add also: Ross, Introduction to Probability Models (7th ed. 2007) as a good reference point.

These books would tell you "here are the distributions we often use, when and why" but I think you are interested in the inverse problem: "Given a setting, what distribution shall I use to model it best?". To my knowledge no such book exists; modeling requires intuition, experience and is data-driven too.

Comment: Thank you, those are very decent suggestions. Would of course welcome others if someone still has one to suggest, but this is already quite helpful.